# Why did Jack Sparrow's crew mutiny?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

We know how, but do we know why? There are clues, but I feel like something big is missing. Given the things Jack did in command (Salazar, Nassau, the bearings for Cortes' treasure), it's unclear why Barbossa had support for the mutiny.

In *Curse of the Black Pearl*, Barbossa gives a clue about the mutiny:

> Jack: "What say we run up a flag of truce, I scurry over to the Interceptor, and I negotiate the return of your medallion, eh? What say you to that?"
>
> Barbossa: "Now you see, Jack, that's **exactly the attitude that lost you the Pearl. People are easy to search when they're dead.** Lock him in the brig."

Comment: I am not so sure that it is as much of a clue about the reason of the mutiny as a suggestion as how would Barbosa would have dealt with it/prevented it, by a ruthless use of force. Also the reason of the interchange is only to expose that Jack is the "nice" pirate and Barbosa the bad one.